# Calculate areas of $0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{y}, 0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{x}, x+y \leq 3 / 4$

Tags: integration, area

I have to calculate the areas of this set.
Could someone explain me how do I have to interprete the following:
\begin{equation}
\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}: 0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{y}, 0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{x}, x+y \leq 3 / 4\right\}
\end{equation}
Thank you in advance.

Comment: try to depict the area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

The purple area is the part under $y=x^2$ plus the small triangle,

$$\int_0^{1/2} x^2 dx + \frac12 \left(\frac34 - \frac12\right)^2 = \frac7{96} $$

Then, the blue area is the difference between the large triangle and twice of purple.

$$\frac12 \left(\frac34\right)^2 - 2\cdot\frac7{96} = \frac{13}{96}$$

Answer (score 0):

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdl4i.png)

I'm sure you can compute the area of the darkest region using integration. (where all of the three colored areas overlap)

- Note that we only have to consider the first quadrant, since $x\geq0,~y\geq0.$

Comment: Yes, that true. My problem was that I didn't understood exactly what the term meant. But now I get it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At first i would calculate the intersection points of the curves
$$x=\sqrt{y},y=\sqrt{x},y=\frac{3}{4}-x$$
I have got
$$\frac{A}{2}=\int_{0}^{\frac{3}{4}}x-x^2dx+\int_\frac{3}{8}^{1/2}x-\frac{3}{4}-x^2dx$$